# Is there any way to create window with size in logical units?

Tags: winapi

I create a window that represents a page, and its size should be determined in millimeters, but CreateWindow function get size in pixels, the only way I thought of is with this code:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    HDC hdc;
    hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    SetMapMode(hdc, MM_LOMETRIC);
    POINT pt[1];
    // get the right bottom point of A4 page
    pt[0].x = 2100;
    pt[0].y = -2970;
    DPtoLP(hdc, pt, 1);
    DeleteDC(hdc);
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, NULL, 0, 0, pt[0].x, pt[0].y, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER);
    return 0;
```

But it seems too cumbersome, is there an easier way?

Comment: No there is no easier way. CreateWindow takes pixels. If you want some other units, you need to convert them to pixels.

Comment: Lots of GUI class libraries address automatic DPI scaling, like Winforms, WPF; Qt if you favor C++.  If you use the raw api then you'll have to hoof it yourself.